# Effect of reference factor on T-test significance for linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, t-test, linear-model

I'm currently attempting to create a linear model in R with some categorical and some continuous variables like as follows:

```
lm(Cost ~ factor(Factor1) + factor(Factor2) + Continuousvariable)
```

I'm aware that when using factors (categorical variables) the default in R chooses the first factor alphanumerically to be the reference factor (i.e. coefficient of 0 in the model).

I've found that in my particular model ordering the factors one way means that these factors have quite high significance (Pr(>|t|)) values however if I reverse the order of the factors changing the reference factor the significance values drop quite considerably.

See sample outputs below:

```
Coefficients:
                                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                       89.644      7.739  11.584  < 2e-16 ***
factor(Factor1)2                  19.252      8.908   2.161  0.03184 *  
factor(Factor1)3                  48.936      7.714   6.344 1.42e-09 ***
factor(Factor2)2                  13.234     10.323   1.282  0.20132    
factor(Factor2)3                  29.701     10.362   2.866  0.00459 ** 
factor(Factor2)4                  66.499     10.849   6.129 4.49e-09 ***
factor(Factor2)5                 117.743     11.364  10.361  < 2e-16 ***
factor(Factor2)6                 155.489     10.077  15.429  < 2e-16 ***
```

Now recoding to reverse factor labels:

```
Coefficients:
                                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                      319.832      6.933  46.135  < 2e-16 ***
factor(Factor1)2                 -29.684      9.208  -3.224 0.001474 ** 
factor(Factor1)3                 -48.936      7.714  -6.344 1.42e-09 ***
factor(Factor2)2                 -37.746     10.369  -3.640 0.000345 ***
factor(Factor2)3                 -88.990      9.725  -9.150  < 2e-16 ***
factor(Factor2)4                -125.788      9.911 -12.692  < 2e-16 ***
factor(Factor2)5                -142.256      9.690 -14.681  < 2e-16 ***
factor(Factor2)6                -155.489     10.077 -15.429  < 2e-16 ***
```

My question is what is the reasoning behind this and is there a rule of thumb when ordering factors to improve the significance of factors in my model?

I hope that makes sense, thanks in advance!

Comment: As a general rule, trying to find ways to twist your data to "improve the significance" of your results is [p hacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging) and a big no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the title of your question implies, changing how a factor is levelled changes the reference level in the regression (i.e. the level that all other levels are compared to.

Imagine a simple case with one three-level factor, with levels A, B and C

```
A <- rep(c(0,1,0), 10)
B <- rep(c(0,0,1), 10)
y <- rnorm(30, 10 + 10*A + 10*B, 2)
x <- factor(rep(c("A","B","C"),10))
```

Which looks like

[image]

I want to know if there's a relationship between this factor and my outcome, so I use a linear regression with A as the reference level

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.8230 -1.4590 -0.6435  1.5663  4.6133 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   9.9215     0.7175  13.828 9.07e-14 ***
xB            9.9643     1.0147   9.820 2.09e-10 ***
xC            8.5194     1.0147   8.396 5.24e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

A is the reference level, so the second variable (after the intercept) is telling us about A vs. B, which is significant, and A vs. C, again significant. This matches what we might guess from the graph.

Now let's change the reference level to C, and rerun the regression.

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ relevel(x, "C"))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.8230 -1.4590 -0.6435  1.5663  4.6133 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       18.4409     0.7175  25.701  < 2e-16 ***
relevel(x, "C")A  -8.5194     1.0147  -8.396 5.24e-09 ***
relevel(x, "C")B   1.4449     1.0147   1.424    0.166    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here, the second variable tells us about C vs. A, which is significant, while the third tells us about C vs. B, which is not. Again, this looks like the graph.

In both cases, the results we get match what we might expect given the data but we see a different pattern of p values because the two regressions are making different comparisons.

In as much as is there a rule of thumb, the rule of thumb should be that the way you code your variables (which includes the reference level) should map as closely as possible onto the hypotheses you wish to test with the regression.

Answer (score 1):

Let us focus on factor 1. Suppose your three levels are A, B and C. If you fit it like that the intercept is A, and the coefficients for B and C compare that with A. If you now reverse it the coefficients compare B and A with C. So far so good as this will look different but, I suspect, comprehensible. Now if you add another factor (D, E, F, G, H, I) as you have it becomes more complex as the reference is now either AD or CI depending which way round you have the factors. Note though that for the levels you are switching the coefficients are just reversed in sign between the two models. If you run `predict` on both models you should get the same predictions. The moral of the story is that testing individual coefficients for significance can be fraught with problems.