# linear regression with categorical variables - what are the estimates of reference levels?

Tags: categorical-data, regression-coefficients

I've been trying with limited success to understand 'reference' levels when doing linear regressions on categorical variables in R. This post:

[Effect of reference factor on T-test significance for linear regression in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233609/effect-of-reference-factor-on-t-test-significance-for-linear-regression-in-r)

helped a bit, but there is still a lot I don't get. I wonder if someone could please answer my questions below and/or point me to relevant literature/posts.

Here's the example I used. I simulated some data about temperatures (Temp) measured at the same time of the day but in different months (Month) and places (Place). There are 12 months {Jan...Dec} and 6 places {A...F}. I assigned a constant value to each Month and Place, and calculated Temp as Month + Place + a random error. Here's what came out:

```
   Month Place  Temp
1    May     E 23.39
2    Dec     B 14.06
3    Nov     E 12.56
4    Nov     F 10.32
5    Aug     C 24.22
6    Jul     A 32.13
7    Oct     E 16.83
8    Feb     E  7.22
9    Jul     E 29.74
10   Aug     F 26.95
11   Jun     D 23.77
12   Jun     B 31.13
13   Dec     D  7.71
14   Sep     B 29.00
15   Jun     C 22.56
16   May     F 20.82
17   Nov     C  6.39
18   May     B 30.33
19   Aug     A 32.13
20   May     A 26.00
21   Apr     D 23.48
22   Jan     F  2.21
23   Oct     B 18.58
24   Mar     B 24.65
25   Dec     C  5.29
26   Jan     B 12.13
27   May     C 20.44
28   May     D 22.52
29   Oct     F 13.12
30   Jan     A  5.56
31   Apr     A 22.79
```

So I ran lm, with the intercept suppressed:

```
m1 <- lm(Temp~0+Month+Place,data=tdata)

sm1 <- summary(m1)

sm1

Call:
lm(formula = Temp ~ 0 + Month + Place, data = tdata)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.9146 -0.7258  0.0000  0.6939  1.5626 

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
MonthApr  24.3526     1.0980  22.179 2.64e-12 ***
MonthAug  30.9107     0.9721  31.797 1.87e-14 ***
MonthDec  10.3452     1.1508   8.990 3.44e-07 ***
MonthFeb   8.2012     1.7111   4.793 0.000286 ***
MonthJan   6.5432     0.9721   6.731 9.61e-06 ***
MonthJul  31.4256     1.0949  28.703 7.68e-14 ***
MonthJun  27.1452     1.1508  23.589 1.14e-12 ***
MonthMar  20.5690     1.6879  12.186 7.68e-09 ***
MonthMay  25.3779     0.8503  29.846 4.48e-14 ***
MonthNov  13.2277     1.1315  11.690 1.31e-08 ***
MonthOct  16.4136     1.1315  14.506 7.92e-10 ***
MonthSep  24.9190     1.6879  14.763 6.28e-10 ***
PlaceB     4.0810     0.9910   4.118 0.001045 ** 
PlaceC    -5.6213     0.9910  -5.672 5.76e-05 ***
PlaceD    -2.4352     1.0431  -2.335 0.034977 *  
PlaceE    -0.9812     1.0299  -0.953 0.356896    
PlaceF    -3.8106     0.9550  -3.990 0.001342 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.366 on 14 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9981,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9959 
F-statistic: 438.7 on 17 and 14 DF,  p-value: 3.789e-16
```

The Estimates are pretty close to the values I used.
However, Place A has no Estimate or statistics.
I understand this is a necessity of the method used. But suppose that I need to make a report for an end user who wants to know about all places and all months.
**Q1**: What Estimate value should I put in that report for Place A? Zero? What error, t-value, Pr? Does it make sense at all to ask this?

Before using R, I used to run this kind of regressions in Maxima (function lsquares_estimates). It was much more complicated, and I could not calculate errors and other stats very easily, but it showed me something interesting.
I ran the exact same problem. One 'dependent equation' was eliminated, and I got non-numerical coefficients as the answer. I.e. there was a real variable added to each coefficient, like:

```
[[Jan=2.732253167457174-1.0*%R1,Feb=
4.386938346498089-1.0*%R1,Mar=16.76057521120221-1.0*%R1,Apr=
20.53682857932274-1.0*%R1,May=21.56761011969353-1.0*%R1,Jun=
23.33233046418485-1.0*%R1,Jul=27.61310220652083-1.0*%R1,Aug=
27.09988869583722-1.0*%R1,Sep=21.11123314105077-1.0*%R1,Oct=
12.60181221694821-1.0*%R1,Nov=9.416826587161458-1.0*%R1,Dec=
6.529998842026064-1.0*%R1,A=%R1+3.812202188790789,B=%R1+
7.892475858976436,C=%R1-1.80953066617677,D=%R1+
1.37794521871563,E=%R1+2.828665973718834,F=%R1]]
```

I guess this is equivalent to saying that F has been considered as a 'reference', and once we choose the value of F, all other values are determined.
In other cases I got more than one dependent equation eliminated, and multiple %R's were present in the solution (multiple references?).
At the time I looked a bit in the literature, and I found (I think in Wikipedia, but I can't find it back) that in such cases one can look for the values of the %R's such that the numerical *range* of the coefficients is minimal.
So in my example, if I take the RHS of the solution as if it were a vector, calculate its norm:

```
18.0*%R1^2-359.1752780077565*%R1+4061.64136679127
```

and differentiate it with respect to %R1 I get:

```
36.0*%R1-359.1752780077565
```

When this quantity is 0, the range spanned by the coefficients is minimised, and that happens for:

```
%R1=9.977091055771005
```

which, substituted in the original solution, yields:

```
[[Jan=-7.244837888313856,Feb=-5.590152709272942,Mar
=6.783484155431175,Apr=10.55973752355171,May=
11.5905190639225,Jun=13.35523940841382,Jul=17.6360111507498
,Aug=17.12279764006619,Sep=11.13414208527974,Oct=
2.624721161177185,Nov=-0.5602644686095726,Dec=-
3.447092213744966,A=13.78929324456182,B=17.86956691474747,C
=8.16756038959426,D=11.35503627448666,E=12.80575702948986,
F=9.97709105577103]]
```

Here the coefficients are all different from the ones I had used, but the ranking is correct within each explanatory variable. So this solution would be satisfactory if the end user only wanted to compare Months among them and Places among them; not really if he wanted to know if Places or Months are more important in determining the temperature. For that I guess R's result is better (although I still need to understand a lot about that).

**Q2**: What do you think about the above method to 'normalise' somehow the coefficients so that all of them can have a defined value? Is it statistically valid? Could one apply this in R? And would it then be possible to calculate the error, t-value and P for each (again, assuming it makes sense)?

Sorry for the long post; I am a beginner in statistics and I can't do technical jargon shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two factors in your model you cannot consider one specified level of one factor (place A in your example) without simultaneously considering which level of the other factor you want to talk about. So in your example you have 12 estimates for place A corresponding to the 12 months. If you alter the order so you get estimates for all 6 places they will all be for the same one month (presumably April). Trying to simultaneously estimate all the months and all the places is, as you suspect, impossible.

Comment: Thank you @mdewey , I think I get what you mean.
I'll spell it out in an answer below, just to check. This comment field is too small.

Comment: OK, turns out I should not post an answer. I'll continue here.
So the solution from R (with no intercept) is something like:
Temp = M(Month) + P(Place)
where M and P are functions that associate an Estimate to each level of the categorical variable. An arbitrary real constant C1 can be added and subtracted without changing the result:
Temp = [M(Month)+C1] + [P(Place)-C1]
which means that R chooses a specific level (in my case, Place A) and assigns its value to C1.

Comment: This explains why when I allow the intercept, R chooses two references:
Temp = intercept-C1-C2 +  [M(Month)+C1] + [P(Place)+C2]
or something to that effect.
So if I really wanted to put in a report the value for the reference values, they would indeed be zero (that's the number R uses when predicting Temp isn't it?).

Comment: If my interpretation is correct, this changes a lot in what I thought the various standard errors, t-values and Pr's meant.
As the reference level changes, C1 (,C2...) may change, and so do all coefficient Estimates. OK, the Temp prediction will not change at all, but if t and Pr are based on testing whether the Estimate is significantly different from 0, obviously in some cases |t| will be very small, and Pr close to 1, not because that specific Estimate is determined less precisely, but just because it numerically approaches 0. This gives me a lot to think about.

Comment: In particular, I tried the `relevel` command as explained in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872070/how-to-force-r-to-use-a-specified-factor-level-as-reference-in-a-regression), setting Place B as the reference. I was relieved to see that the anova table didn't change compared to the case when Place A was the reference.

Comment: However, I was expecting the standard errors on each Estimate to change in such a way that their relative error would remain the same. Instead the Estimate for Place E went from -0.9812+/-1.0299 to -5.0622+/-1.0415, which makes a big difference, at least in my inexperienced eye, in how 'reliable' the coefficient for Place E is. I'm probably looking at this from the wrong angle though, because the standard error on the Temp prediction should be, if I'm not mistaken, independent from this effect. I will look for literature about that; I suspect it is some function of the summary sigma value.

Comment: It is hard to follow the track through all those comments. May I suggest (a) edit them all into your original question, or (b) if they are really asking a fresh question then post them as such with a link back here?

Comment: OK, sorry. I thought it was wrong to edit my question, otherwise the answers below would not seem pertinent anymore. But if this is the rule, I will follow it. In essence I was just spelling out my understanding of the problem after reading your explanation, to check if I got it right. I looked just now at the error on the estimates, and found that thr `se.fit` option of `predict` already takes care of that. And it's exactly the same regardless of what reference level is used. Great! R is really impressive - one needs to be motivated to learn it though: it's no walk in the park. Tx

Comment: Add it as an edit, do not take out the original.